# FactoryGirl doesn't update counter field for associated object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, counter, factory-bot

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :success_criterion
end

class SuccessCriterion < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :topics, dependent: :restrict_with_error
end
```

`SuccessCriterion` manages a `topics_counter` counter, but it doesn't seem to be updated when using the following factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :topic do
    success_criterion { create(:success_criterion) }
    title             'Topic test title'
    intro             'Topic test intro'
    outro             'Topic test outro'
  end
end
```

Take a look at the following:

```
@topic             = create :topic
@success_criterion = @topic.success_criterion

@success_criterion.topics.any?
=> false
@success_criterion.topics_count
=> 0
@success_criterion.topics.count
=> 1
```

What's happening here? Without the `topics_counter` field, it works as expected, so it seems the FactoryGirl doesn't seem to update the counter when doing `success_criterion { create(:success_criterion) }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable `counter_cache` in your model.

Add the following to your `Topic` model:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :success_criterion, counter_cache: true
end
```

Be sure that the `topics_count` column is present in your `SuccessCriterion` model.

Ryan Bates described this feature very well in one of his [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column).

Comment: Stupid, stupid, stupid! ;-) Programming Rails for years now, and asking something like this... Unbelievable! Thank you.